# Google Calendar feed timeMin timeMax not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, feed

I have inferred from my searches that the URI for a Google Calendar feed that limits the date range should include timeMin and timeMax and should also include singleEvents and orderBy.  This is the URI that I've constructed:

https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/myuserid@gmail.com/public/full?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2014-01-01T00:00:00&timeMax=2018-03-24T23:59:59

Regardless of what query parameters I put after the projection value, I still get back all events dating from 8/2008 through whatever future dates I have in the calendar.

I really am "constructing" this based on very little knowledge.  Can anyone set me straight, please?

Comment: I am using the googleapis node package, and still getting this same result, both providing Date objects and iso strings with the Z for timezone.... not sure what todo....

Answer (score 6):

It also took me quite some trials and errors to realize that offset is actually mandatory, not optional, as documented in
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts

Try to add "Z" to the end of your URL:

https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/myuserid@gmail.com/public/full?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2014-01-01T00:00:00Z&timeMax=2018-03-24T23:59:59Z

Comment: But in this way, you will miss for example two hours if you are in the Central Europe timezone (i.e. 12 AM ~ 2 AM)

Comment: @BenyaminJafari, could you elaborate on that?Also, are you talking about the same version of the API?

Comment: Imagine you have an event in your google calendar at 1 AM and your local timezone is Berlin which differs by +2 hours from UTC. Then you want to get to  the whole events on a specific day. In this way, you will miss the event at that time due to the timezone. So it is better to put the exact timezone instead of `Z` (UTC time). And I'm using version 3.

Comment: Makes sense. My post was from 2014 so it was probably V2. The doc URLs are also different now. But thanks for providing an example.

Answer (score 0):

Mastoll, I think you are using calendar v3, is that right?  You may try:
[https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/myuserid@gmail.com/public/full?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&start-min=2014-01-01T00:00:00&start-max=2018-03-24T23:59:59&](https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/myuserid@gmail.com/public/full?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&start-min=2014-01-01T00:00:00&start-max=2018-03-24T23:59:59&futureevents=true)

You can try using start-min and start-max instead of timeMin and timeMax.  This is the parameter for calendar v2, I don't why, but v2 parameter works for public calendar.  You can also add the futureevents=true parameter.  For the details information for v2, please refer to the following:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference?hl=de&csw=1#Parameters