# Google calendar feed link does not respect the parameters

Tags: api, rss, google-calendar-api, feed

I try to use this link to show the upcoming events but there is not respect my params form link have anyone any idea how to fix this? It is showing the whole events. Even the past ones

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mariushincu0%40gmail.com/public/basic?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&timeMin=2015-04-25T00:00:00Z

Comment: is this not the same as this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322221/google-calendar-feed-timemin-timemax-not-working?

Comment: is not but seems to be same question. anyway I have added Z on the end

Comment: I really meant the "start-min and start-max instead of timeMin and timeMax" and "add the futureevents=true" bits

Comment: it still don't work. I've selected to show me event from june but it still showing events from tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said previously this is the same as the previous post in as much as you need to change the parameter "timeMin" to be "start-min"

Therefore the answer for your URL is

https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/mariushincu0%40gmail.com/public/basic?singleEvents=true&orderBy=startTime&start-min=2015-04-25T00:00:00Z